# Refresh Fragment Listview with Custom BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, fragment, android-adapter

I have been pulling out what little hair I have left trying to resolve this.  I have my Main activity that has a "multi-functional" refresh button.  This refresh button does several things, but it needs to end by refreshing a listview I have on one of the attaching fragments.

The refresh button on the main activity is always visible, no matter what fragment is visible.  This button is doing everything it's suppose to except refreshing the listview on one of the fragments.  This is my fragment class:

```
package xxx;

import ...

public class Fragment_OpenTickets extends Fragment {
    INT_OnTicketSelectedListener mCallback;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ticketList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public interface INT_OnTicketSelectedListener {
        public void onOpenTicketSelected(HashMap position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mCallback = (INT_OnTicketSelectedListener) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Context context = getActivity();

        DBController dbc = new DBController(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_opentickets, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.openList);
        Cursor cursor = dbc.getAllOpenTickets();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                int size = cursor.getColumnCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    hashMap.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getString(i));
                }
                ticketList.add(hashMap);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        final Adapter_OpenList adapter = new Adapter_OpenList(ticketList, context);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
                HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(pos);
                mCallback.onOpenTicketSelected(obj);
            }
        });

        dbc.close();
        return view;
    }

}
```

This is the custom BaseAdapter:

```
package xxx;

import ...

public class Adapter_OpenList extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ticketList;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public Adapter_OpenList(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr, Context c){
        ticketList = arr;
        context = c;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ticketList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ticketList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_openticket_row, null);

            holder.txtTicketNo = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_ticketNo);
            holder.txtTicketDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_ticketDate);
            holder.txtLease = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_lease);
            holder.txtDelivLoc = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_delivLoc);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        HashMap map = ticketList.get(position);
        holder.openID = map.get("id");
        holder.txtTicketNo.setText((CharSequence) map.get("ticketNo"));
        holder.txtTicketDate.setText((CharSequence) map.get("ticketDate"));
        holder.txtLease.setText((CharSequence) map.get("lease"));
        holder.txtDelivLoc.setText((CharSequence) map.get("delivLoc"));

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        Object openID;
        TextView txtTicketNo;
        TextView txtTicketDate;
        TextView txtLease;
        TextView txtDelivLoc;
    }
}
```

I've tried detaching the fragment, used notifyDataSetChanged() and other things.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Here is my main activity.  It's a work in progress so go easy on me:

```
package xxx;

import ...

public class Activity_Main extends Activity implements Fragment_OpenTickets.INT_OnTicketSelectedListener, Fragment_Ticket.INT_SubmitNewTicket {
    DBController dbc = new DBController(this);
    Fragment fr;
    Button refreshBtn;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //openAdapter = new Adapter_OpenList(null, this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (dbc.checkCredentials() != null) {
            fr = new Fragment_OpenTickets();
        } else {
            fr = new Fragment_Settings();
        }
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        refreshBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh);
        View.OnClickListener ocRefresh = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                refresh();
            }
        };
        refreshBtn.setOnClickListener(ocRefresh);
    }

    // Top menu buttons.
    public void selectFrag(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio_open:
                fr = new Fragment_OpenTickets();
                break;
            case R.id.radio_submitted:
                fr = new Fragment_SubTickets();
                break;
            case R.id.radio_settings:
                fr = new Fragment_Settings();
                break;
            default:
                fr = new Fragment_OpenTickets();
        }
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    public void onOpenTicketSelected(HashMap position) {
        // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected ticket.
        fr = new Fragment_Ticket();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("HashMap", position);
        fr.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    public void SubmitNewTicket(HashMap data) {
        // Insert ticket into local queue tickets DB table to be sent to server.
        dbc.insertQueTicket(data);
        // Insert ticket into local submitted tickets DB table.
        dbc.insertSubTicket(data);
        // Delete ticket from local open tickets DB table.
        Integer id = (Integer) data.get("openID");
        dbc.deleteOpenTicket(id);
        // Redirect user to Open Tickets activity.
        fr = new Fragment_OpenTickets();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    public void refresh() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        //SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        final AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        final RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        final String[] userInfo;

        // Show progressBar.
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, null, true, false);

        // Check queue for tickets.
        if (dbc.checkQueTickets() != null) {
            Cursor cursor = dbc.checkQueTickets();
            int columns = cursor.getColumnCount();
            int rows = cursor.getCount();
            final ArrayList<Integer> queueIDs = new ArrayList<>();
            final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<>();

            // Get user info.
            userInfo = dbc.checkCredentials();

            // Add user info and request type to params so server knows what we're doing.
            params.put("username", userInfo[0]);
            params.put("password", userInfo[1]);
            params.put("request", "submitTicket");

            // Add SQL data to params to be sent.
            for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair(cursor.getColumnName(c), cursor.getString(c)));
                    //map.put(cursor.getColumnName(c), cursor.getString(c));
                }
                params.put(String.valueOf(r), map);
                queueIDs.add(Integer.valueOf(map.get(DBController.COLUMN_ID)));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            // Send ticket(s) to remote server.
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.50.5/app/api.php");

                    //Encoding POST data
                    try {
                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        // log exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //making POST request.
                    try {
                        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // Log exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            thread.start();


        } else {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getRemoteOpenTickets();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    private void getRemoteOpenTickets() {
        String[] userInfo;
        userInfo = dbc.checkCredentials();
        if (userInfo != null && userInfo.length > 0) {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://192.168.50.5/app/api.php?request=getOpenTickets&username=" + userInfo[0] + "&password=" + userInfo[1]);

            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                if (responseStr != null && !responseStr.equals("")) {
                    dbc.updateSQLite(responseStr);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //refreshScreen();
            progressDialog.dismiss();


        } else {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public void refreshScreen() {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.detach(fr);
        fragmentTransaction.attach(fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

I feel like I need to re-create the adapter (reset it), but I can't figure out how to do that.  It seems so dependent on the onCreateView method in the fragment class.

Comment: Can you share code you are doing to refresh the list view on click

Comment: Where is refresh Button